# create and index views combined in 1 view

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to be able to add players and upon addition in the same I want to display them in a table similar to what page Index view offers. so what I did is combine the index and create views in 1 page.

but when debugging I'm have a resource cannot be found error.

can some one please correct where I'm going wrong

**Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<sportsMania.player>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>category</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Player Name")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("Player Name")

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Team")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("team", ViewBag.team as SelectList)

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Position")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("position")

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("email")

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Type")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("type")

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Height")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("height")

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.playerName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.team)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.position)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.height)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.playerName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.team)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.position)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.height)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

**playerController:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace sportsMania.Controllers
{
public class playerController : Controller

{
    sportsEntities db = new sportsEntities();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = from p in db.Teams

                   select p.teamName;

        SelectList list = new SelectList(data);
        ViewBag.team = list;

        return View(db.players.ToList());
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(player player)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            player newRecord = new player();
            newRecord.playerName = Request.Form["Player Name"];
            newRecord.position = Request.Form["position"];
            newRecord.type =Request.Form[ "type"];
            newRecord.team =Request.Form[ "team"];
            newRecord.email = Request.Form["email"];
            newRecord.height = Request.Form["height"];
            db.players.Add(player);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(player);

    }
}
}
```

why I am doing this? because I don't want every time the user have to add a Player he should be redirected to the create view, I want when user finishes adding players he will hit a button "done adding" and will be redirected home.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you're asking but the exception being thrown is caused by the `Create` action trying to find a (presumably deleted) view called 'Create'. If you want the `Create` action to return the `Index` view, then it needs to `return View("Index");` ... or `return View("Index", player);` for the `Post` action

Comment: I want both create and index in 1 view as the title indicates, meaning the user will fill the textboxes with data and when hit the add button the record created is shown in the same page in a table at the buttom of the page